# Separate repo for each release of Flutter project?

Tags: git, flutter, version-control, repository

I'm taking over development from another developer who couldn't meet the timeline requirements of my new client, and I'm trying to make sense of why they have a repo set up for each separate release.

The app is not yet public, so these builds are for client demoing. Each repo consists of the web build files with a single commit. The client said that it's because the developer preferred to use microservices rather than a monolithic architecture and doesn't have any other details.

I can't find any information about this pattern, and I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction and do further research. Or to let me know if it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone other than Person X could tell you *why* Person X did what Person X did. We could *speculate* (i.e., guess) but that's about all.

Comment: This is someone who doesn't get git, perhaps.

Comment: @torek, yeah, I just wanted to ensure that I am speculating, and this isn't a novel pattern or architecture I'm unaware of.

Comment: Can't you consider the last repo update or release build because this something like PersonX may be keeping all the backup folders for each feature and later your client must have asked him to push the code with all features.